Why isn't there power to receptacles on my GFCI breaker circuit?
We switched out old receptacles to new ones with screw less plates.  So far we got 54 of them working and the last three we switched out totally killed the power to the circuit.  The GFI is in the circuit breaker and there is power to the breaker when I turn it on there is a green light, and I also clicked on the “test” reset a few times and nothing would send power to the receptacles on that circuit.  Yesterday all of the receptacles worked after we replaced but 3 left.  The three we replaced today turned off the power to all of the receptacles on that circuit.

Got the line and load cables connected to the correct terminals?

Does the GFCI breaker stay turned on when you turn it on?  Does the TEST button trip the breaker?  Did any sparky events occur during the work?  Shorting hot to neutral would not trip the GFCI but would cause a current surge which could "burn out" a poorly made connection at a prior receptacle, e.g. a backstab or a side screw that was not torqued with a torque screwdriver as mandated by NEC 110.14(D). That "burn out" could even happen before the breaker tripped from overload.

If you installed 54 outlets successfully, and then three more unsuccessfully, surely you can do a better job at figuring out which one of the three is problematic, and what you did differently.  Be a little more systematic and describe your detailed observations in the question.

GFCI detects a current imbalance between hot and neutral. That can happen because:

Damaged appliance or receptacle
Exposed wire in a cord (damaged insulation)
Water in an appliance or receptacle
Improper wiring

Since the problem happened when replacing receptacles, my bet is on improper wiring.
One of the 3 receptacles has a problem, possibly more than one. Some possibilities include:

Neutral and ground connected together
Hot and neutral reversed (if everything else is done properly, this should not actually trip a GFCI, but make sure anyway)
Damaged insulation
Damaged receptacle (not likely with new receptacles, but stranger things have happened)
Short between receptacle screws and metal box (if a hot screw shorts then it will trip any breaker, if a neutral screw shorts it will only trip a GFCI)

